# How to keep the reference voltage constant for comparator?

Tags: comparator, voltage-reference, tl431

I want to build a circuit with a comparator, but the reference voltage is changing (CH3-purple) as seen in the oscilloscope image.[image]

I used the [TL431](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tl431.pdf) as in the image to keep the reference voltage constant. However, I couldn't fix it completely. How can I fix it?

Comment: What are the values of the resistors and capacitors in the circuit? What is providing the 5 V supply?

Comment: Lots of ground noise and load error.  Increase R values x10

Comment: The positive feedback path is a varying load. When output is low, more current is drawn than when output is high. The question is, how much are the currents and how much current it both cases still flows via TL431? Maybe the resistance values are not suitable. What are the resistance values?

Comment: Buffer it with an op amp?

Comment: What does the layout look like?